# Python Real-time Busy Polling a Database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a database table that gets row/record `INSERTS` from a third-party application. This table has one column labeled 'active' that is always `False` when each new record is INSERTED by the third-party application.

My application needs to read rows on that database table, and find those rows that have the 'active' column with a Boolean value of `False` and then UPDATE the column to `True` (after doing some processing on the row).

What is the best way to do this? Right now I just have a simple while loop that repeatedly queries the database and processes that table. But I think there must be a better way.

My question is: What is the proper way to busy-poll a database in Python so that my application notices changes to the DB as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider doing a trigger in the DB that fires of a script to you application, instead of polling the DB.

This would probably best be done with the help of [PL/sh](http://plsh.projects.postgresql.org/)

Comment: You could also use a subscriber pattern and have the trigger issue a NOTIFY. The code would issue a LISTEN and then loop waiting for notifications (see the async notifications section here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html - sqlalchemy gives you access to the psycopg connection object to do this).

Comment: Also, depending on your use case, you could just do all your processing in the trigger.